# Fastest Search and Insertion

Tags: search, data-structures, hash

I ve got a million objects . Which is the fastest way to lookup a particular object with name as key also the fastest way to perfrom insertion ? would hashing be sufficient?

Comment: In which language? Are the objects sorted or not?

Comment: in C . The objects are not sorted

Answer (score 4):

Probably a hash table, assuming you don't need anything other than key based access. Make sure that the hashing of the key is good enough (as to minimise collisions) and the table is large enough (for the same reason).

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how often your need to do a lookup and how often you need to insert elements.

If you often have to insert elements then a linked list would perform better.

If you often have to search for elements, an hash table is more efficient. Perhaps, you can have both - your main data as a linked list, and an hash table which will serve as an index to the list.

Comment: A linked list will suffer atrocious performance if you need lookup. A hash table is sufficient (O(1) expected insertion).

Comment: why would an array be asymptotically more efficient for search? Did you mean a hash table?

Comment: Yes I meant an hash table. It's faster to access an element by index in an array but not to search for one. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: But then why do you need the linked list at all?

Comment: I guess insertion is still faster with a linked list since there's no hash to generate. But I don't really know how he wants to use his data, so perhaps a hash table alone is enough.

Comment: Well, if you're maintaining *both* a list and a hashtable, insertion will take the slower of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a binary search tree. BST has the advantage of fast search and fast insertion too. Use the key to route your way in the tree and build  the tree node to have the value.

Use BST in favor of hash tables if you are not sure about the balance of the operation (ie: looking up a key and value pairs, insertion, etc) and if you (based on your analysis) know that keys may collide frequently in the hash table (which will cause bad performance for the hash table).

Answer (score 1):

Several Structures exist here that you can use. Each has it's advantage and disadvantage.

A HashTable will have a great lookup time and insertion time, provided you have a table that minimizes collision. If not, then lookup/insertion can lead to a lot more time.

A Binary Search Tree has ln(n) insertion and lookup, provided that it's balanced. Sometimes the balancing can cause the insertion to take a bit longer then ln(n), depending on the BST you go with.

Answer (score 1):

Can go with B+ tree, it guarantees lesser search complexity ( since you reach leaf nodes fast, height = log n to base k, k = degree of nodes). The databases have similar requirement and they use B+ trees to maintain and retrieve data.